# Highlight tab on new event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a function that changes the title with the code below, and whenever the window is on focus than it must stop the changing.

```
//Set to true on first load
var window_focus = true;
$(window).focus(function () {
    return window_focus = true;
})
        .blur(function () {
            return window_focus = false;
        });
// THE CHANGE FUNCTION
function doHighlightNow (){
    var highlightTimer = null;
    var oldTitle = document.title;


    function doHighlight() {
        if (window_focus){
            stopHighlight();
        }

        var doBlink = function() {
            document.title = "Title one"

            setTimeout(function(){
                document.title = "Title two";
            }, 1000);
        }
        doBlink();
    }

    function stopHighlight() {
        document.title = 'stopped';
        clearInterval(highlightTimer);  
    }
    highlightTimer = setInterval(function(){doHighlight(nickname) }, 2500); 
}
```

Now this will change the title everytime `doHightlightNow()` is triggered and `windows_focus` is not `true` else it clears the interval.

Now I want to make it trigger `stopHighlight()` directly whenever the window is on focus again and if `doHighlightNow()`is triggered, what is the best solution for this.

I now it must be something like,

`$(window).on("click", "focus",function(){
   trigger stopHighlightnow();
});`

But i don't know exactly how to provide this, I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is,

```
var highlightTimer = null; // Create it outside the function 
                           // So you can stop it outside the function
function doHighlightNow (){
    var oldTitle = document.title;

function doHighlight() {
    //No need for this inside the function
    //if (window_focus){
        //stopHighlight();
    //}

    var doBlink = function() {
        document.title = "Title one"

        setTimeout(function(){
            document.title = "Title two";
        }, 1000);
    }
    doBlink();
}
// Neither need this anymore inside the function
//function stopHighlight() {
    //document.title = 'stopped';
    //clearInterval(highlightTimer);  
//}
highlightTimer = setInterval(function(){doHighlight(nickname) }, 2500); 
}

    $(window).on("focus", function(){
        if (window_focus){
            document.title = 'stopped';
            clearInterval(highlightTimer);  
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a better way to do what you want, you have a built in event for this:

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
  if(document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
    document.title = "Title one";
  } else {
    document.title = "Title two";
  }  
});
```

Comment: The title one/two is allready working, what i want is to `clearInterval` if the window is focus (must be live)